# How do I move where an image displays with Drupal?

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, content-management-system

I'm trying to make my first Drupal site, and I need to get news posts to display like:

```
[  user  ] NEWS TITLE
[ posted ] Content content content content
[ image  ] Posted by Admin on 9/15/11
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to move the title to where it needs to be. I figured out that `$content` controls both the "user posted image" and "Content content content" sections, but I can't figure out where I can go to edit `$content` in any of the `tpl.php` files.

On a side note, how do I make multiple news items appear on one page?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?  What is the name of the content type that is a "news item"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! What I did was added `hide($content['field_image']);` to part of the code, and then `<?php print render($content['field_image']); ?>` where I actually wanted it to display. Worked out perfectly.